# HTTP error code 420 at standard sales cloud pages

Tags: error

Today, all our users have had Salesforce pages intermittently fail to load with only the error message `http error 420`. The developer console also doesn't provide additional information to the cause of this error.

This isn't a standard error code and I can't find anything related to it. We've recently turned on `Salesforce Edge Network` but I don't think that should be a cause for this.

We've tried the usual things to fix  this like removing cookies and login out and back in but that hasn't helped. Status.salesforce.com doesn't show any problems for our server. I've already opened a case but they can take a while so I'm hoping the community knows something.

If you have the same problem let me know and I'll add you to the case.

[image: HTTP ERROR 420]

Comment: Are you really getting an http 420, the weed/pot status code, from salesforce? Also, the salesforce edge network is really unstable, there are weekly to monthly global outages, and salesforce doesn't take any ownership of the outages. It's a total mess with no accountability. status.salesforce.com also doesn't show outage information, it's not a useful page.

Comment: @AndyRay Hahaha, yes we are getting the 420 error code, I was surprised by that too. Thank you for letting me know the Edge Network is unstable. It's been generally available for a while now so I figured it'd be stable. Support got back to me and they have disabled our Edge Network implementation. I'll post an answer tomorrow after our users have confirmed that the issue is gone. Salesforce wants to make the Edge Network madatory in a couple of months so that'll be interesting.

Comment: Today and yesterday they had a global edge network outage, one of dozens this year. They don't update status pages, the system just goes down until people start complaining https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/786

Comment: @AndyRay You're right, it's an Edge Network issue and I don't think I'll be told the actual reason. The good news is that some massive companies (Coca-Cola, Pepsi, Dell) also had this outage so at least they're taking it seriously. If you don't mind, would you put your insights in an answer, then I'll accept it,

Comment: I turned on the Salesforce Edge Network in one sandbox and after 5 minutes I could no longer log in to the sandbox. HTTP error 420. Upon googling I found this page. In detail: my username+password is accepted, but I land in the 420 page. Cannot do anything anymore with the sandbox.

Comment: After a while I succeeded accessing the sandbox again. To my surprise, the Salesforce Edge Network was now off! I think I won't touch this setting again, not for sometime.

Comment: Thanks @SanderdeJong, good to know I shouldn't turn it back on any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was from one of the many global edge network outages this year. Salesforce didn't notify anyone of the outage until hours after it started. https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/786

Additionally, drug friendly or not, I find it quite unprofessional to serve a 420 status code to paying customers.

Comment: To me 420 didn't have a special meaning. I just looked it up in the list of HTTP codes and couldn't find it there. Additional googling taught me another meaning. So 420 does not have a special meaning to everyone :-)

Comment: The 420 Code seemingly has nothing to do with drugs.

It was originally from the Spring Framework, defined as `420 METHOD FAILURE`, and the Dataloader application *(and who knows what else on Salesforce's end...)* is built on the Spring Framework. Spring has since deprecated this error code, but it can be assumed that whatever Salesforce is using is still built on a version of the Spring Framework that still has that error code.

That said, the Twitter API ***does*** have a 420 error code that is a drug reference, and is meant to tell HTTP Clients that they're now being rate-limited.