# Is there an active Salesforce OAuth outage this morning?

Tags: rest, oauth

It appears that multiple services were unable to oauth to salesforce this morning.

I'm curious if anyone else saw this in their systems.

We're not sure what's happening, it's not a credentials issue. We're wondering if Salesforce had edge network DNS issues and our client applications had issues resolving DNS for token endpoints.

Comment: Possibly related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/361836/http-error-code-420-at-standard-sales-cloud-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now know this is one of the dozens of global "Edge" network outages this year. The lack of transparency and accountability from Salesforce is astounding. https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/786